# mediafilesegmenter error on h.264 video encoded with ffmpeg

Tags: ios, streaming

I'm trying to segment a video for use with http streaming on iOS devices with no luck...

The idea is that this will be part of an automated process, so I'm doing the initial conversion of the video with ffmpeg, and then do the segmentation using Apple's mediafilesegmenter tool.

Every time I run the command, I get the following error:

```
Apr 13 2011 10:18:57.097: Processing file XXXXXXX.mp4
Apr 13 2011 10:18:57.364: track 0 of XXXXXX.mp4 contains edit list that the media doesn't start at beginning; these tracks cannot be used for segmentation
Apr 13 2011 10:18:57.364: No valid tracks found
Apr 13 2011 10:18:57.364: average bit rate is 0 - max file bit rate is 0
```

I'm at a loss for what I could do different with ffmpeg... Converting the file with quicktime produces the correct results. ffmpeg seems to be causing the issue...

Answer (score 6):

For anyone interested, I was able to resolve this by remuxing the source into an MPEG2 TS container. Use the following command:

`ffmpeg -i {original mp4} -vcodec copy -acodec copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb {output}.ts`

From there it segments fine. This is a quick command since no rendering is done.

Comment: Hey! Do you have any other ways? Because I tried it now and faced the same issue. Thanks!